# How do you Alter a column in Oracle SQL to only allow it to take in two values, either a Y or a N?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Most of the results I have seen were for MySQL. I understand that `Alter Table` is to be used, as well as `MODIFY`, but after that I am stuck

My table in question is this:

```
CREATE TABLE store_reps
(
rep_id NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
LastN VARCHAR2(15),
FirstN VARCHAR2(10),
comm CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y'
);
```

For the comm column, I want to set it where it can only allow either "Y" or "N". I hope this is enough to help solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a `check` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE store_reps (
    rep_id NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastN VARCHAR2(15),
    FirstN VARCHAR2(10),
    comm CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y',
    CONSTRAINT chk_store_reps_comm CHECK (comm IN ('Y', 'N'))
);
```

Or after the table is created:

```
ALTER TABLE store_reps
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_store_reps_comm CHECK (comm IN ('Y', 'N'));
```

Comment: Actually, I do not want to change the table, I want to use `ALTER TABLE` to modify the value

Comment: @Laser . . . You can use the same syntax in an `ALTER TABLE` statement.  Just be careful if there is already data in the table.

Comment: Oh? There were no values already in yet, so that is not problem for me. Mind if I ask what I should do if there were already values in? Would I have to remove them?

Comment: @Laser . . . You would not be able to add the constraint if any rows violated it.

Answer (score 1):

Alter the table and add a `CHECK` constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE store_reps
  ADD CONSTRAINT store_reps__comm__chk CHECK (comm IN ('Y', 'N'));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f86d3ca2c8edc9ab8d3abcfef1a6f2dc)*